# Can Redux manage just a boolean?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-thunk

I have a piece of state in my React & Redux App dealing with **authentication**. It's a `boolean`.

I'd like to simplify grabbing this piece of state from the Redux store but can't find examples of this.

Is this approach a bad idea? I know that mutating state is **not** the correct approach. I'm not sure if this constitutes a mutation though.

```
import {
  AUTHENTICATED,  
  AUTHENTICATION_ERROR,
  AUTHENTICATION_REMOVE,
  UNAUTHENTICATED,
} from '../actions/types';

let INITIAL_STATE = false

export default function( state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case AUTHENTICATED:
      return !state

    case UNAUTHENTICATED:
      return state

    case AUTHENTICATION_ERROR:
      return state

    case AUTHENTICATION_REMOVE:
      return !state

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're authenticated and in some way manages to authenticate again, you're not authenticated?

Comment: I guess this would be one edge case. However I was reading about design patterns recently and I really do believe in this saying right here.

https://imgur.com/a/tOxt9JX

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly fine. Because you are not mutating anything from the state.

Yes, You are not mutating the `state`. Because your state is just a `boolean` value and you are returning the opposite value of your state. But you are not making any change to the state.

```
const value = true;
console.log(!value) // This will not change the value directly but it just returns false
```

But try to use a `key` in the state. In future, if you want to add some more keys. You don't have to do so many changes.

Answer (score 1):

When your state is just a boolean, you aren't actually mutating the state by writing `!state`, since `boolean`, `string` and `number` values are immutable.

Also it might not be a bad idea to store just a boolean in the reducer state. However you must read [`You Might not need Redux`](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367) to undestand more on when you should and should not use redux

Answer (score 0):

You can try this enhancer [redux-named-reducers](https://github.com/mileschristian/redux-named-reducers)

Then your reducer is simplified to something like this:

```
authModule.reduce(AUTHENTICATED, { isAuthenticated: true })
authModule.reduce([UNAUTHENTICATED, AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, 
AUTHENTICATION_REMOVE], { isAuthenticated: false })
```

Then you can access authentication state from anywhere like this:

```
getState(authModule.isAuthenticated)
```

I'm being very strict with the authentication state here to be set only when authenticated, and unset for everything else, but you can adjust as you see fit.